# Flutter/Dart ListView not displaying snapshot.data

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, snapshot

I am simulating taking data from a json api file (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts), but it is not displaying the containers on the screen. In the text below, I mention the ListView part, that I believe is the problem, because when I tested with ListTile, it worked.

```
 Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 550, bottom: 50),
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getTechies(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                print(snapshot.data);
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Container(
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text("Loading...", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),)
                      )
                  );
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                        return
```

I believe the problem is the ListView part, because I tested with ListTile and it worked

```
  ListView(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                            children: <Widget>[

                                    InkWell( // on tap...
                                    child:
                                      Container(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                                        width: 180,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        boxShadow: [
                                        BoxShadow(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        blurRadius: 0.5,
                                        ),],
                                        ),
                                          child:
                                        Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: <Widget>[

                                          Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                            Text(snapshot.data[index].body.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                            SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                            Text("AS: " + snapshot.data[index].id.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                                            SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                            Text("AC: " + snapshot.data[index].userId.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                                            SizedBox(height: 30,),
                                            ],
                                            ),

                                          GestureDetector( //on Long Press...
                                          child:
                                            Container(
                                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                            width: 120.0,
                                            height: 40.0,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                      

      color: Color(0xffeb5c68),
                                                ),
                                                child:
                                                  Column(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            

  children: <Widget>[
    
                                                Text("REQUEST", textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                                                ]
                                                )
                                                ),
                                                onLongPress: (){

                                                
                                                );
                                                },
                                                )
                                                ]
                                                )
                                                ),

                                                onTap: () {

                                                }
                                                )

                                                ],

                                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal);                              
                          }
                      );
                    }
                  }
              )
              ),


Future<List<Technician>> getTechies() async {
    try {
      var data = await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
      var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);


      List<Technician> techies = [];

      for (var u in jsonData) {
        Technician myTechy = Technician(u["userId"].toString(), u["id"].toString(), u["tittle"], u["body"]);

        techies.add(myTechy);
      }
      return techies;

    } catch(e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete Future builder code?

Comment: It is just that. If you substitute the `return ListView` for `return ListTile(
                              title: Text(snapshot.data[index].userId.toString()),
                              subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].id.toString()),
                            );` it will show the data!

Comment: You cant return ListView instead of ListTile you just need to return code wich you have written  inside children[] i.e InkWell widget

Comment: It showed me the error: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#dcfb5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///home/cabral/Desktop/rider_jopa/rider_jopa%20(teste2)/lib/main.dart:187:31

Answer (score 1):

Its because you can't set container height.

So(for example) set container height like this,

```
InkWell(
 // on tap... 
child: Container( 
padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), 
margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
 width: 180,
Height:100,//its a example height, you can change this as your requirement 
)
)
```